# Core plot : how to change plotSpace.xRange dynamically when device orientation change?

Tags: ios, core-plot, xrange

I've got an iOS app whith many charts. I would like to modify the xRange value when the charts is displayed in landscape mode but I can't have Core Plot doing this.

I tried to totally recreate the graph by calling

```
[graph removePlotWithIdentifier:@"myGraphName"];
```

in "WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation" and then building my graph again with new xRange but it doesn't worked.

I would like CorePlot to dynamically adapt the xRange depending on the device orientation.

I've got this code to manage a different xRange depending on the device orientation on first creation of the graph:

```
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
   || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(lengthToDisplay/2) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(lengthToDisplay/2)];

} else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
          || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(lengthToDisplay) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(lengthToDisplay)];
}
```

It works fine. But if the graph is already displayed and I change the device orientation nothing happens. I tried to put this code in "WillRotateToInterfaceOrientation" but again, nothings happens.

Comment: Does this code actually execute? Use an `NSLog` statement to find out. What version of iOS are you testing on? The way device rotation is handled changed starting with iOS 6. See Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html).

Comment: This code execute : I haven't put everything here but I handle other change depending on device orientation and those change are done when device orientation change. I've tried it on iOS6 and earlier. Can't understand why the range isn't updated....

Comment: What is `plotSpace`? Is it a reference to the plot space actually in use by the graph? What is the value of `lengthToDisplay`? What type is it?

Comment: Yes, plotSpace is a reference to the plotSpace actually in use by the graph : `CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;` and lengthToDisplay is calculated based of the number of points to display, it's a NSInteger : `NSInteger lengthToDisplay = [Data_graph count] * graphTimeFrame;`